# Sorting an IEnumerable<type> by three fields

Tags: c#, sorting, ienumerable

I have defined a type as follows:

```
public class myType
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string middleName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}
```

I have an `IEnumerable<myType>`.

I want to use the `.OrderBy()` extention to sort my list of myType as follows.

The objects should be in order by last name.  Where the last names are the same, they should be in order by first name.  Where the first names are the same, they should be in order by middle name.

How do I do this?

Comment: (the members will need to be *accessible* (usually: `public`) to sort on them; and properties would generally be preferred over fields)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var qry = items.OrderBy(x => x.lastName).ThenBy(x => x.firstName)
    .ThenBy(x => x.middleName);
```

or in LINQ syntax:

```
var qry = from x in items
          orderby x.lastName, x.firstName, x.middleName
          select x;
```

Comment: +1. Remember that the lambda can be any code that returns a string, so you could, for example. perform a null check and return some non-null default value. I do not know how the built-in QuickSort behind most .NET sorters will handle nulls. Also, though OrderBy() claims to be a stable sort, if it does then it doesn't use the built-in sorter which also powers List.Sort and Array.Sort, and is unstable.

Comment: @KeithS: It doesn't have to return a string. It can be anything that returns a value, so long as the values can be compared for ordering later. And yes, OrderBy really *is* stable.

Answer (score 8):

```
myList.OrderBy(t => t.lastName).ThenBy(t => t.firstName).ThenBy(t => t.middleName)
```

Also, each `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` have a `Descending` Version, so `OrderByDescending` and `ThenByDescending`